# Fiori Elements - Customize $batch query

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have Fiori applications using fiori element and I want to tweak the odata queries that UI5 generated for OData in `$batch` calls.

I have livemode turned for the list report along with smartfilter for selection/filter and `list of values` using ValueList annotations. But the problem is when I type in the filter value in selection fields (lets say for sold to) the `$batch` call fires the below query for OData.

```
../invoice_list.xsodata/vlsoldto?sap-client=100&$skip=0&$top=10&$filter=startswith(SOLDTO___T,%27TEST%27)
```

I want to tweak the the odata call to use 'substringof' instead of 'startswith'.. so something like below.

```
../invoice_list.xsodata/vlsoldto?sap-client=100&$skip=0&$top=10&$filter=substringof(%27TEST%27,CRM_SOLDTO___T)
```

I don't know the spot where I can do this customization. I know how to do Fiori elements extensions, but looking for some info if its an extension then which type of extension, which event, or any other approach if not extension. I have very little idea on where to start.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose zou talk about the Combobox ? See 'Filtering the Option list' here: 
https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/combo-box/#filtering-the-option-list

Comment: Mine is a multiInput. But when I add setFilterFunction as below, it doesn't change filter to contains (rather than startsWith)
****************************************************************************
oMultiInput.setFilterFunction(function(sTerm, oItem) {
    // A case-insensitive 'string contains' filter
    return oItem.getText().match(new RegExp(sTerm, "i"));
   });

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own fields in the SmartFilterBar and then create your own custom filter:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3a515829ffd74239878ebc0d453d001d

**Edit:** if you want to use the existing fields you can just push a new filter with `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains` on the [`beforeRebindTable`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/events/beforeRebindTable) event.

*Step 1:* Register your extension in your **manifest.json** file

```
"extends": {
   "extensions": {
      ... 
      "sap.ui.controllerExtensions": { 
         ...
         "sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.view.Details": { 
            ... 
            "controllerName": "com.acme.app.controller.ListReportExtension",
            ...
         }
      } 
      ...
```

*Step 2:* implement the controller method:

```
sap.ui.controller("com.acme.app.controller.ListReportExtension", {
        onBeforeRebindTableExtension: function(oEvent) {
        var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
        oBindingParams.parameters = oBindingParams.parameters || {};

        var oSmartTable = oEvent.getSource();
        var oSmartFilterBar = this.byId(oSmartTable.getSmartFilterId());
        var vCategory;
        if (oSmartFilterBar instanceof sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar) {
            //Custom price filter
            var oCustomControl = oSmartFilterBar.getControlByKey("CustomPriceFilter");
            if (oCustomControl instanceof sap.m.ComboBox) {
                vCategory = oCustomControl.getSelectedKey();
                switch (vCategory) {
                    case "0":
                        oBindingParams.filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Price", "LE", "100"));
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        oBindingParams.filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Price", "GT", "100"));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```